# Booting from USB fails on desktop not macbook

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.5. When I try to boot from the usb I get the options "install Ubuntu 14.04" and "try without installing" (and others). No matter which option I select, I get the purple Ubuntu boot screen and then my screen goes black and nothing else happens.

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.10. I created a bootable usb with Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 16.10. I've verified the .iso file beforehand. I also have no problem booting from the usb on my macbook air. I've tried reformatting the usb (Master boot record Fat32) with my macbook and using UNetbootin to try and create the installation media but have the same issue.

My desktop is an ASUS Z720M plus MB with intel core i7. I've looked for any kind of setting pertaining to "allow boot from USB" in the BIOS, but I can't find anything. The fact that I at least get the Ubuntu logo makes me think that the BIOS settings may not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a video problem, what video hardware do you have?  Did you try "nomodeset" (edit the grub "try..." command, add nomodeset where "quiet splash" words are on the line starting with "linux".